# HTML draw multi images on one canvas

Tags: html

I have a project about chess . I use a canvas and set background to create a board. Then draw 32 pieces on it. I used requestAnimFrame to redraw 32 pieces after a piece moved. But when I move a piece the screen blinks. Can u explain it or where am I wrong ?

Here is my code : 
Class game:

```
this.true = false;
this.b = new Boards();
this.ctx = canvas;
animate();
game = this;
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  this.valid = false;
})

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if(!game.valid) {
    game.b.clear(game.ctx);
    game.b.draw(game.ctx);
    game.valid = true;
  }
}
```

Class Board

```
function draw(ctx) {
  imgChessman = new Image();
  imgChessman.src = "/path/src";
  imgChessman.onload = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
      if(boards[i][j]) {
       boards[i][j].draw(ctx);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to take a look at html5 frameworks , because they have layering capablities
you can put each pieces in different layers and just change its x and y , personally i prefer to use createJs [enter link description here](http://www.createjs.com/) it has a good online documentation for start and it is really easy to use

Comment: thank your sharing :). I figured out , i reload image each time I redraw :(